# Javascript form error - script doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am testing out a script I wrote for a calculator, I am using HTML form elements to take in the user input value and calling a function in an external script whenever that button is clicked

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //on add buttton depressed, fire event which calls the initializer function
    $('#form3').on('click','button',function () {
    var ans = $(initializer());
    $('#form6').text(ans); 
    });
});
</script>   
<div id="wrapper">
<p>INPUT TEXT IN ROMAN NUMERALS</p>
<form id="form1" class="" >
    <input type="text" id="form2" class="" width="1"/>  
    <button name="button" id="form3" class=""> + </button> 
    <input type="text" id="form4" class="" />  
    <button name="button2" id="form5" class=""> = </button>
    <input type="text" name="result" id="form6" class=""></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my function that is located in an external JavaScript file which is called when user clicks the button with `#form3` as an `ID` (I include it in the `head` element)

```
function initializer ()
{
    //contains user input in first box
    var userinput_a  = $('#form2').val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    //contains user input in second box  
    var userinput_b  = $('#form4').val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    try
    {
    if(!validity(userinput_a, userinput_b))
    {
      throw exception;
    }
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert('Wrong values put in the right value');
    }

    var combinedtext = userinput_a + userinput_b;
    var stage1 = romanexpanded(combinedtext);   //text contains roman to expanded
    var stage2 = expandedtoroman(stage1);       //text contains expanded to roman

    return stage2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dvgqu/2/

I have looked into the code but I, apparently, can't find out what is stopping my script from running properly, whenever I click the button that calls my function the values in my input boxes disappear.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:
I have used the javascript debug console and from walking through my code I deduce it is either the way I am calling the initializer function or the way I am accessing the form value, the only problem is I don't see whats wrong with my syntax or logic.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Maybe you could post the error that you're getting?

Use the Firefox or Chrome Javascript debug Console. They are good developer Tools and made for such situations.

Comment: I don't understand the line $('#form2').val($(this).val().toUpperCase());

Comment: You get "{"error": "Please use POST request"}" initially. If you add the post method to the form, you get other errors: http://jsfiddle.net/Dvgqu/1

Comment: I am not getting any specific error the input the user puts into the textbox disappears when the (=) button is clicked.

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir that line converts the value in the input box to Uppercase, i need the values in uppercase cause i use it later in my code

Answer (score 2):

Just `.text(stage2)`. There's no reason to wrap with `$` the result from `initializer` :

`.text(initializer());`

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate is incorrect. This:

```
$('#form3').on('click','button',function () {
    var ans = $(initializer());
    $('#form6').text(ans); 
});
```

won't work, since `#form3` **is** the button. As @user1737909 states, you don't wrap your function call in a jQuery selector. Also, use the `.val()` method:

```
$('#form3').on('click', function () {
    var ans = initializer();
    $('#form6').val(ans); 
});
```

Comment: look at initializer definition

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir The code inside it looks fairly wonky (I have no idea what the OP is trying to do), but the end result seems like it should be a string. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes the final result should be a string